# Telling makefile to search different directory for C header file(s)

Tags: c, search, makefile, directory, header-files

I've been trying to figure this out for a little while now and I am at the point where I am out of guesses/ideas.

I am making some C programs for a numerical analysis class at school and many of the programs use utility functions that I've written beforehand. I'd like to have the utility "library" in a separate directory from the class programs, but be able to include the utility header files when needed.  Below is the structure of my "setup" (+ = directory/folder, - = files)

```
 +Code
    +Classes
         +Fall_11
              +Numerical_Programs
                  +Bisection
                      -.c and .h file(s) for bisection
                       +linux
                            -makefile
    +util
        +CompareFloats
            - CompareFloats.h
```

So basically, I have Bisection.c and Bisection.h within the directory Bisection. Bisection.c uses floating-point comparison functions that are within CompareFloats.h, in the util/CompareFloats directory.

Below is the makefile I've been trying to use:

```
###############################################################################
#       makefile for Bisection test                           #
###############################################################################


#--------------------------------Macros----------------------------------------#
COMPILER = gcc
UTIL = ../../../../../util/CompareFloats
FLAGS = -ggdb -Wall -lm -I$(UTIL)
OBJECTS =  ../Bisection.o ../BisectTest.o $(UTIL)/CompareFloats.o
OBJECT_DIR = ../OBJECTS
EXEC = BisectTest

all :   $(EXEC)
    test -d $(OBJECT_DIR) || mkdir $(OBJECT_DIR)
    mv $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECT_DIR)

$(EXEC) : $(OBJECTS)
      $(COMPILER) $(FLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)

#-----------------------------Dependencies--------------------------------------#
Bisection.o :       ../Bisection.h
BisectTest.o:       ../Bisection.h 
CompareFloats.o:    $(UTIL)/CompareFloats.h

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) *.o $(OBJECT_DIR)/*.o
    rmdir $(OBJECT_DIR)
```

I understand that the -I flag will allow header files to be searched for in other directories. I figured I was using it correctly, but I can't get it to work. I just get an error that CompareFloats.h does not exist (I've double checked the path and it is correct). Inside Bisection.c, I have

```
#include "CompareFloats.h"
```

like usual. The only way I can get this to work is to have the #include statement contain the relative path, like

```
#include "../../../../util/CompareFloats/CompareFloats.h"
```

(it has one less ../ because Bisection.c is one level up from the makefile).

Any suggestions? I'd really like to just have #include "CompareFloats.h" instead of the relative path.

If I am not providing enough information, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you print out the actual compile command that is run?  If you are using make, it should print out a line like `gcc -ggdb ...`

Comment: cc    -c -o ../Bisection.o ../Bisection.c
../Bisection.c:10:27: error: CompareFloats.h: No such file or directory
../Bisection.c: In function ‘bisect’:
../Bisection.c:32: error: ‘EPSILON’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../Bisection.c:32: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../Bisection.c:32: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [../Bisection.o] Error 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is in the auto rule generated for `Bisection.o`.  You can do one of two things:

1) make a rule for the `Bisection.o`:

```
Bisection.o :       ../Bisection.h
        gcc -c -o ../Bisection.o -I$(UTIL) ../Bisection.c
```

2) append the include flag `-I$(UTIL)` to the variable `CFLAGS` (these are the flags passed to the C compiler)

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) -I$(UTIL)
CXXFLAGS=$(CXXFLAGS) -I$(UTIL)
```

Most people also end up needing

```
LDFLAGS=$(LDFLAGS) -I$(UTIL)
```

but you don't yet.

Comment: isn't CXXFLAGS for the C++ compiler? (question asks for C programs)

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys. Embarrassingly, my knowledge of makefiles has been pretty limited. They haven't explicitly taught us the details in school, so I've been learning it as I need it, and by looking at the more "professional" makefiles at my work/internship. I've already updated all my relevant makefiles and everything runs perfect.

Comment: @Foo Bah: it is. I have the habit of setting both.